# Working with datetime in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

How to properly extract a **time** only from the **datetime** object (`post.created_at`, to be precise) with/without the influence of `TimeZone`? How to extract the `day`, `month` and `year` values? How to extract the `day/month/year` via a custom pattern (is it possible)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Time in String format:

```
post.created_at.strftime("FORMAT STRING HERE")
# Without the influence of time-zone: I take it that you want UTC
post.created_at.utc.strftime("FORMAT STRING HERE")
```

Link for the `strftime` documentation:
    http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#method-i-strftime

For getting the hour, minute and second values:

```
post.created_at.hour
post.created_at.min
post.created_at.sec
```

Comment: Brief explanation, example code and link to documentation. A stellar answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= l(@issue.created_at, format: :your_format) %>
```

in locale YAML (app/config/locale/country_id.yml) you must declare

```
time:
 formats:
  your_format: '%d %b. %Y'
  your_another_format: '%I:%M'
```

Date formatting should be declared inside your i18n YAML definition file for easy configure, and other date format could be found here.